# How to convert multiple values from SDO_GEOMETRY to WKT format?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-spatial, wkt

I am aware that I can convert ORACLE SDO_GEOMETRY to WKT format. But, I don't know how to convert it if it contains multiple values. How do I do that?

I have the following table:

| ID | SDO_GEOMETRY |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(9971, 19188, NULL), NULL, NULL) |
| 1235 | SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(9972, 18282, NULL), NULL, NULL) |
| 1236 | SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(9977, 19201, NULL), NULL, NULL) |
| 1237 | SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(9993, 18225, NULL), NULL, NULL) |
| 1238 | SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(10035, 18367, NULL), NULL, NULL) |

I would like to convert all these values to WKT at once. How do I do that?
What I tried so far?

```
CREATE TABLE new_test ( name varchar2(20), geom SDO_GEOMETRY );

INSERT INTO new_test (name, geom)
VALUES (
  '1234', 
  SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(9971, 19188, NULL), NULL, NULL);
  
);

SELECT NAME, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOM) AS point FROM NEW_TEST;
```

The above script converts only one at a time. How do I implement that for multiple rows?

Answer (score 2):

You describe a CREATE TABLE, then an INSERT that puts only one row in the table and then a SELECT. If your description is verbatim, your last SELECT should - and will return only one row (because the table has only one row).  SELECT... sdo_util... from NEW_TEST as is (without a WHERE clause) will (convert and) return all rows of that table.

Answer (score 0):

you could use  SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY("name_of_ur_geometry_column") as GEO_WKT an then save it to a csv,txt or whatever you need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).